# Random Password Generator based on user input

Tags: python, python-2.x, random

This is my second program written in python. It basically creates a password made up of numbers, capital and lower case letters with the option to include special characters and dashes. I created a simpler project and I decided to build upon it to create version 2. Since I am still new, I would like to receive advice and any thoughts on how to improve my code as well as a programmer. Such as how random this password is, any syntax errors, or any ways to simplify my code. I commented as best as I could. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
#version 2 introduces option to include special characters and 
the option for the password to be separated into
#sections by a dash as well as a more secure and better created 
password which has no certain pattern to it
#as the previous version did

#loop goes through steps until user decides to quit
# 1. ask for user input if special characters can be added and set 
     to var response
# 2. come up with random number between 1 and 3, set = to var 
     typevalue if special is no
#    come up with random number between 1 and 4, set = to var 
     typevalue if special is yes
# 3. assign randint between 0 and 25 to lowercase and uppercase 
     var, assign randint between 0-9 to number var,
#    assign randint between 0-9 to character var
# 4. if type=0 number value is added to objects list
#    if type=1 upper[uppercase] is added to objects list
#    if type=2 lower[lowercase] is added to objects list
#    if response is yes and only yes, characters[character] is 
     added to objects list

from random import randint

upper = 
["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M",
 "N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
lower = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m",
         "n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
characters = ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","_","+"]

objects = []


def RunFun(a,b):
    typevalue = randint(a, b)
    lowercase = randint(0, 25)
    uppercase = randint(0, 25)
    number = randint(0, 9)
    character = randint(0, 9)
    if typevalue == 1:
        objects.append(upper[uppercase])
    elif typevalue == 2:
        objects.append(number)
    elif typevalue == 3:
        objects.append(lower[lowercase])
    elif typevalue == 4:
        objects.append(characters[character])

def RunType2(c,d):
    first = c
    second = d
    for i in range(16):
        RunFun(first, second)
    Function1()


def Function1():
    dashes = raw_input("Would you like it to be seperated into" 
    four sections of four characters divided by a dash? 
    Y for yes N for no: ")
    if dashes == "Y" or dashes == "y":
        #print "dashes %s" % (objects)
        print "%s%s%s%s-%s%s%s%s-%s%s%s%s-%s%s%s%s" % (
            objects[0], objects[1], objects[2], objects[3],
            objects[4], objects[5], objects[6], objects[7],
            objects[8], objects[9], objects[10], objects[11],
            objects[12], objects[13], objects[14], objects[15])
    else:
        #print "no dashes %s" % (objects)
        print "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s" % (
            objects[0], objects[1], objects[2], objects[3],
            objects[4], objects[5], objects[6], objects[7],
            objects[8], objects[9], objects[10], objects[11],
            objects[12], objects[13], objects[14], objects[15])


#-------------foundation-----------
while True:
    #requests user input which determines if special characters 
    #are included
    answer = raw_input("Can it have special characters? Y for yes 
    N for no. X to exit: ")

    if answer == "Y" or answer == "y":
        RunType2(1,4) #hands over value 1 and 4 to include 
                      #characters in the creation
    elif answer == "N" or answer == "n":
        RunType2(1,3) #hands over values 1 and 3, opts out 4 
                      #which is special characters
    elif answer == "x" or answer == "X":
        exit()
    else:
        print "Invalid Input."
            del objects[:]
```

Answer (score 3):

- At the top of the module use triple quotes to document things instead of using comments. At the top level it will also act as a docstring for your module.
- Use `random.choice` on the iterable instead of getting a random int first and then using it get an from iterable.
- `if answer == "Y" or answer == "y"` etc can be replaced with `if answer.lower() == "y"`.
- Use better variables names, for example `a` and `b` in `FunRun(a, b)` doesn't make any sense.
- Use new style string formatting instead of the old sprintf based syntax. Or better join `str.join` in your case if you want to merge bunch of items.
- Your code has too many PEP 8 issues as per [PEP8 online](http://pep8online.com/) tool. You should check [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and use extensions like `flake8`, `pylint` etc to catch those.

Answer (score 2):

**I use Python 3, so I am unsure if all of these suggestions apply to Python 2.**

## String module

You can use the [string module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) instead of manually typing a, b, c / A, B, C / 1, 2, 3 etc.

## Naming

Your function `RunFun()` should have a more descriptive name. As it is, looking at your code, I wouldn't understand what the name had to do with the actual code. Maybe `select_values`. This goes for your other functions too: `RunType2()` and **especially** `Function1()` are really bad names.

## "".join()

You can make use of `"".join()` in `Function1()`, to clean up the code.

## Answer in []

Instead of `if answer == "y" or answer == "Y":`, use `if answer in ["y", "Y"]:`. This is much more clean-

## Comments

Some of your comments are, frankly, useless: `#requests user input which determines if special characters #are included`, `answer = raw_input("Can it have special characters? Y for yes N for no. X to exit: ")`.

## Decoration

Get rid of this:

`#-------------foundation-----------`

## PEP-8

Follow [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

- Functions should use `lowercase_with_underscores` capitalization;
- Comments should ideally be on a new line, and should start with a single space and a capitalized letter, for readability;
- You should consistently leave two newlines in between functions;
- You should split sections of code with a single newline for readability.

## Security

You are using the *random* module, [which is not fit for security purposes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html/):

> Warning The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used 
>   for security purposes. Use os.urandom() or SystemRandom if you require a 
>   cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator.

While Python 3.6 offers a *secrets* module, I am unsure about Python 2.x. Please, however, don't make the mistake of using *random* for generating passwords.

Right now, it seems that your password generator is quite weak. The password entropy remains low, which means you must resort to using `os.urandom()` and asking the user to provide enough entropy.